# How can i check apk file is already install in my Emulator?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android, appium-ios

I already install apk file in my emulator by Providing path in Desired capabilities

```
DesiredCapabilities cap= new DesiredCapabilities();

cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP,System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/test/resources/app/"+"Facbook_AU-release-6.5.apk");
```

But i don't want to install apk file in every test case execution
How can i handle this?

Comment: Just remove the above capability - `MobileCapabilityType.APP`. Don't put that, if you don't want to install.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use this capability if you have the app installed on the Emulator/Device.

Instead of that using this:

```
caps.setCapability("appPackage", "<APP_PACKAGE_NAME>");
```

Replace the `<APP_PACKAGE_NAME>` with your application packageName.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

yes, I agree with @adrenalineWest. But if you've already installed apk file just simply check in the emulator ie, open emulator and search for the required app.

If you want to know the 'app activity' or 'app package' then run the following command in cmd.

**dumpsys window windows | grep -E ‘mCurrentFocus’** 
for more infor refer this link http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/

Answer (score 0):

@amit, you can verify using below the api(isAppInstalled) in your code. Its response will be Return true if installed, false if not (boolean)

```
boolean appExist = driver.isAppInstalled("com.example.AppName");
if(!appExist){
  System.out.println("app is does not exist");
else{
  System.out.println("app is already installed");
}
```